# Translating MATLAB's `fminsearch` with its constraints to scipy's `minimize`

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, mathematical-optimization, minimization

I want to maximize the log likelihood function of GARCH model, I am using `fminsearch` in MATLAB to minimize the negative log likelihood function, there are two constraints in this problem. I tried to use the `fmin` or `minimize` functions (from scipy) but I think the way of translating the constraints is incorrect.

Below is my attempt in python 3.6:

```
def computeNegLLH(parameters):
    sigma2 =  np.zeros(len(returns));

    omega = parameters[0];
    alpha = parameters[1];
    beta  = parameters[2];
    sigma2[1] = parameters[3];

    # parameters restrictions: omega>0; alpha,beta>=0; alpha + beta >= 1
    if (omega<=0 or min(alpha,beta)<0 or alpha + beta >= 1 or sigma2[0]<=0):
    negLLH = sys.maxsize;
    sys.exit();

    # calculate squared returns
    returns2 = returns**2;


    for t in range(1,len(returns)):
    sigma2[t]= omega + alpha*returns2[t-1] + beta*sigma2[t-1];

   # calculate (-1)xLogLikelihood for a GARCH(1,1) process with parameters
   negLLH = 0.5*sum(log(sigma2) + returns2/sigma2);
   return negLLH


result = minimize(fun = computeNegLLH, x0 = startingValues, method = 'Nelder- 
Mead', options = {'xtol': 1e-8})
```

My MATLAB code:

```matlab
function param = calibrate_GARCH(returns, startingValues)
    % computes maximum likelhood estimates for a GARCH(1,1) process give
    % timeseries "returns" using fminsearch function 
    options = optimset('TolX',1e-12,'MaxFunEvals',3000,'Maxiter',3000, 
    'Display','off','LargeScale','off');
    param = fminsearch(@(param)computeNegLLH(param,returns), startingValues, 
    options);
end

function negLLH = computeNegLLH(param,returns)
    % param for the given timeseries returns
    sigma2 =  zeros(size(returns));

    omega = param(1);
    alpha = param(2);
    beta  = param(3);
    sigma2(1) = param(4);

    % parameter restrictions: omega>0 alpha,beta>=0
    % ensure that GARCH(1,1) process is covariance-stationary
    if omega<=0 || min(alpha,beta)<0 || alpha + beta >= 1 || sigma2(1)<=0;
        negLLH = intmax;
        return;
    end

    % calculate squared returns
    returns2 = returns.^2;

    for t=2:length(returns)
        sigma2(t)= omega + alpha*returns2(t-1) + beta*sigma2(t-1);
    end
    % computes (-1)xLogLikelihood for a GARCH(1,1) process with parameters
    negLLH = 0.5*sum(log(sigma2) + returns2./sigma2);
end
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to post your _working_ MATLAB code alongside your python attempt.

Comment: @Dev-iL Thanks for your comment. I have just added my MATLAB code to the post. I hope you can be able to help me now.

Comment: Your question is sorely missing a [mcve]. Why do you think it's wrong? Do you have a _simple_ example where you have an issue?

Comment: Thanks @AndrasDeak for your comment. When I run the code I get this error message: SystemExit.

Comment: `sys.exit();` is actually `return negLLH` which means that the function will terminate and return the `negLLH` value. Also `returns` is not defined in the python code, look at the `args` option for minimize, it is used for for additional parameters. You could do it also with a anonymous function `lambda x:f(x, args)` similar to the matlab code

Comment: Thanks @xdze2. returns is a vector her, which represents the stock market returns. I also tried args option, but it doesn't help as well!

Comment: I think you must change 'sys.exit()' to 'return' function.

Comment: This is a *bad* way to handle constraints! Instead of the solver knowing that it's in an unwanted region, all it will see is the cost going to infinity—no! Please use [`scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint.html#scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint) in Scipy or [`fmincon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html)/[`fminsearchbnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8277-fminsearchbnd-fminsearchcon) in Matlab!

Comment: And of course get rid of `sys.exit();`, that's going to cause Python to quit as soon as the search enters a constrained region!